# Symfony doctrine specify fields in ManyToOne to improve performance?

Tags: sql, performance, symfony, doctrine

For example i have a simple entity "Cars" with a ManyToOne relation "Brands".

```
class Brands
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $country;
}

public function getCountry(): ?string
{
    return $this->country;
}
```

Cars entity :

```
class Cars
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Brands")
     */
    private $brand;
}


public function getBrand(): ?Brands
{
    return $this->brand;
}

public function getBrandCountry(): ?string
{
    return $this->getBrand()->getCountry();
}
```

If on my template i do {{ car.getBrandCountry}} (or {{ car.brand.name}} on template), the request executed on database will do :

```
SELECT t0.id, t0.name, t0.field3, t0.field4, t0.field5 [..........] FROM brands t0 WHERE t0.id = ?
```

But i only need "name" or "country" field from Brands, not others. On my list i have 500 lines to display and Symfony did 500 SELECT * only for load 2 fields that is very bad for performances.

How i can do to obtain something like that (to get only fields i need, not all fields.) :

```
SELECT name, country FROM brands WHERE id = 'xx'
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the only chance you have is to prefetch only the required attributes in the controller and access only this data passed to the template/twig. Otherwise doctrine will make these queries for you.

Comment: Ok i understand, i can do like an array with brands[id] and pass it to the twig template but it look like very dirty. I can't believe i can't just select things i need instead of doing a bad select *.

Comment: You have to make a custom query in your repository class then make a dependecy injection in your controller and pass that to your view.

Comment: You can avoid the extra queries by making a custom query and joining the brand entity.  The docs have examples.  The current two answers are pretty much bogus.

Answer (score 0):

There are three solutions to your problem :

1. You build a first query which will collect the content of the `brands` table.
   With doctrine cache, when you will query the `cars`, doctrine won't query the `brands` table again as it have it in it's cache.
2. You query your `cars` table, collect the brand ids from the result and then query your `brands` table with the ids you collected. In this case, you will not do something like `cars.brands.name` in twig (else doctrine gonna make extra query). I would suggest to rebuild `brands` array result to make an associative one (`[brand_id]=>[brand_data]`)
3. Make a partial query : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/partial-objects.html

Answer (score 0):

The best practices is to add a new function in Repository of your Entity, and use it after in your controller for ex in your case:

```
  public function getCustomDataById($brandId)
  {
       return $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
                ->select('b.name, b.country')
                ->where('b.id', $brandId)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
  }
```

Comment: I suspect a better practice would be one that works.  Doctrine DQL is not SQL.

Comment: Yes of course, i know i can do this, but if i did this i can't get it on my Entity or on my Template. Except if i do an associative array like it was suggested by Preciel.